# Sentiment Analysis Dictionaries - positive, negative, neutral

Tags: r, python, natural-language, sentiment-analysis

I would like to classify user comments in reply to articles on news portals, especially in my country. Many comments are tweet-like in length but others can be quite long (a few hundred words).

I tried an example in R (example analysed tweets) that uses Naive Bayes but am not satisfied with the results. I have turned to Python and found quite a few examples.

I have been looking all over the place to see whether I could find all three types of dictionaries but have only managed to find the positive an negative ones. I have looked at quite a few SO posts especially [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188706/sentiment-analysis-dictionaries) and all those others that were suggested to me after typing the question both on SO and CV. The reason I am looking for all three types of dictionaries is that I am following [this tutorial](https://pythonspot.com/en/python-sentiment-analysis/) and thought that I would replace the `positive_vocab` and `negative_vocab` in the example with the contents of Bing & Liu's [Opinion Lexicon](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html#lexicon). So far so good, but in the same example there is also a `neutral_vocab` with around 10 words.

```
neutral_vocab = ['movie', 'the', 'sound', 'was', 'is', 'actors', 'did', 'know', 'words', 'not']
```

So I looked to see whether I could find a "neutral dictionary" of words similar to what Bing & Liu have. Does one such dictionary exist, or is it that the reason I could not find one is that I'm a complete dork and do not really need one as neutral words could be defined as all those words that are not positive or negative?

Could anyone please help me out in this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

People don't usually use these fixed dictionaries of positive/negative/neutral words except for programming exercises. In naive bayes, which is closer to what people actually do, you give each word a score. Negative scores are negative sentiment words and positive scores are positive sentiment words. The words with scores near zero could be thought of as neutral words.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your kind explanation and my apologies for the late reply.